# Minimizing $\mbox{tr} (WX)$ subject to $\mbox{tr} (KX^{-1}) = n$ and $X \succ 0$

Tags: optimization

Minimize g:
g=tr(WX) 
and X=TT^t

Under the constraint 
tr(KX^(-1) )=n
and
X=TT^t

K,W  are symmetric and positive definite matrices

T is not singular

T∈R^nxn     ,K,W ∈R^nxn  , n is scalar

For which matrix T we have the minimum g?

Comment: T∈R^nxn     ,K,W ∈R^nxn, n is scalar